# 1.clone 2.copy 3.null original 4.transport undetected

Tags: javascript, function

Is this the correct way to null (or clean up a variable so it does not exist), **then** pass it to a private function undetected by the parent scope, or do I have any bugs here?

```
(function(){

    function second(secret){
        //maybe do code stuff here (use imagination)
        console.log(secret);
        }

    function first(){
        var hidden=Math.random();
        //maybe do code stuff here (use imagination)
        (function(){var copy=JSON.stringify(hidden);hidden=null;second(copy);})();
        }

    first();

    })();
```

Disclamer: This exercise is subject-less, with no defined point unless imagination is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Cleaning up your values and variables is done by the garbage collector automatically. Simply pass the value to the other function:

```
function first(){
    var hidden=Math.random();
    //maybe do code stuff here (use imagination)
    second(hidden);
}
```